# Mediawiki Authentication Issue

Tags: linux, wiki, mediawiki, system-administration

I just took over control of our organization's MediaWiki. It is currently configured to use LDAP to authenticate users. However, the admin account, apparently, isn't authenticated through LDAP (I say so because a hashed entry for user_password exists for admin in the user database but not others). But, our login page has no option to specify this! https://i.stack.imgur.com/t58FN.png

I have tried resetting the admin password using changePassword.php, createAndPromote.php but I still can not login as admin!

Any ideas on what I can try now?

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow local users in addition to LDAP users.  Set this in your LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgLDAPUseLocal = true;
```

But as Tgr suggests, you should make an LDAP user an admin and then disable this, since it tends to cause no end of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just give admin rights to some other user.